# converting a user inputed string into a new object

Tags: c#

I created a class I named Cashiers(shown below). I can create new instances through code no problem. What I can not do is *have a user input a string value into a string variable I named `CashierLOgInNName`*. So if the user inputs the value as `DSPR` I want to be able to create a new cashier object by that name, or the equivalent of

```
Cashiers DSPR = new Cashiers();
```

I've included the parts of my code that pertain to this question.  Ideally if I could have the line or lines of code that would enable me to have this work and why that be excellent.

```
public class Cashiers
{ 
    public int CashierID;
    public int Password;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName; 

    public void SetCashiers(int CashierID, int Password,string FirstName, string LastName )
    {
        this.CashierID = CashierID;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public void SetNewCashier(int CashierID, int Password, string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        //Cashiers NewCashier = new Cashiers();
        this.CashierID = CashierID;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("enter New Log in name");
string CashierLOgInNName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How does Activator.CreateInstance Method work?

Comment: ... but why would you want to do that? It's not like you're setting the name of your cashier, you're setting the name of the _variable_. This is an horrible idea and impossible to maintain, at best.

Comment: Why would you want the user to be able to input variable names for instances? How would you be able to use that?

Comment: Echoing Pierre - for what possible reason would you ever need the names of your objects in code to match any input provided by the user? The code of your program is of no concern to your user, and structuring the names of within your code based on your user input shouldn't be a concern of yours.

Comment: im writing a program that would handle transactions for a store. it requires a cashier to login. there is also a manager mode that needs to be able to create new cashiers. there is also an Inventory class I created that an admin could create new instances of. But once  understand how to get this to work I can apply it to that.

Comment: @DANS80 And how does all this have to do with using the user input to manage how you name your **variables**? I think there's multiple key concepts you are not understanding.

Comment: But what would naming your variables after user input accomplish? The names of variables have nothing to do with the actual function of your code. Why would you insist on being able to have the name of your variable be altered at run-time to share the same value as your user input? What if their input is the same as the name of a compiled variable? What you're asking is not only useless but actively harmful to the development of any safe system.

Comment: @DANS80: You should study classes further before continuing down this path. If all you're trying to do is allow a user to login thereby creating a new instance of `Cashiers`, it is much easier than the question you are asking.

Comment: yes, trying to create a new instance of cashiers. in my full program I have several created which is no problem. but lets say there is a new hire, I want the admin to create a new cashierID. so if his name is mark jones and when prompted to enter user id. and the admin enters MJONES. I need the code that would be the equivalent of: Cashiers MJONES = new Cashiers();that way a coder wouldn't have to manually do it every time someone is hired. if I asked that unclearly,i apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To more directly answer with your example, building on the best method of using a dictionary (aka Key Value Pair):

```
Dictionary<String,Cashiers) dictCashiers = new Dictionary<String,Cashiers>();
Console.WriteLine("Enter new login name:");
String CashierLogInName = Console.ReadLine();
Cashiers newCashier = new Cashiers();

dictCashiers.Add(CashierLogInName,newCashier);
//replace constants in the next line with actual user's data, probably input from more ReadLine queries to user?
dictCashiers[CashierLogInName].SetNewCashier(1,2,"Jane","Doe");
```

You can see **dictCashiers[CashierLogInName]** accomplishes what I believe you are looking for, and retrieves the Cashiers object associated with that Login ID.

Comment: yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. and yes you guessed it, I have more readline statements gathering the rest of the data. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @DANS80.  Also, instead of using 'SetNewCashier', I would suggest moving that to the object constructor, so instead of calling `dictCashiers[LoginName].SetNewCashier`, you can condense 3 lines to one:    `dictCashiers.Add(CashierLogInName,new Cashiers(1,2,"Jane,"Doe") );`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you're really looking for is either a database (which is too broad to answer here) or a dictionary.

In a dictionary, you'll be able to store your `Cashier` objects *keyed* by a `string`. You aren't affecting the name of the variable, of course, but you can still use that name in a theoretical context to get at what you're looking for. If you did actually change the name, that would lead to a need for reflection, which is messy and slow.

```
private Dictionary<string, Cashiers> dict = new Dictionary<string, Cashiers>();

private void Save(string name, [probably some other details?])
{
    dict[name] = new Cashiers(); // or whatever
}

private void Print(string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dict[name]);
}

private void PrintAll()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict.Select(c => c.Key + "\t" + c.Value.ToString()));
}
```

Obviously my implementation here leaves something to be desired, but it shows how you can use it.